# modinfo does not return self inserted module's information

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

### The Scenario

I'm trying Kernel Programming for Linux, where I've created module, Inserted, Removed and checked it's output in `dmesg` as well

### The Problem

When I have inserted module, I can verify that it is inserted successfully by firing `lsmod`. Yet, when I fire `modinfo` it returns an error saying it isn't present there. follow the below terminal snippets

**INPUT**

```
sudo insmod hello.ko
lsmod | head -2
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
hello                  16384  0
```

**INPUT**

```
sudo modinfo hello
```

**OUTPUT**

```
modinfo: ERROR: Module hello not found.
```

### Questions

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. If not, what is the other way I can get it?
3. I tried finding it from nautilus browser in filesystem, which doesn't return any result. Where do I find it's file on Insertion?
4. Is it loaded on temporary purpose, may that's why I can't find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`modinfo` by default searches in `/lib/modules/<kernel-version>`. So you would have to copy your kernel module in a subdirectory in there. Most likely `/lib/modules/<kernel-version>/extra`.

After copying your module in the right place, you also should execute `depmod -a`.

Comment: Depmod -a was the thing I missed. Rest I did it already!.

Comment: `pegasus@pegasusv:~$ lsmod | grep hello


helloworld  16384  0
pegasus@pegasusv:~$ modinfo helloworld
modinfo: ERROR: Module helloworld not found.
pegasus@pegasusv:~$ sudo depmod -a
pegasus@pegasusv:~$ 
`

I ran depmod -a. But still modinfo can't find the helloworld module loaded by me.
and there's no extra directory. So where should I put my helloworld module?
and should I copy the whole helloworld directory?

Comment: `pegasus@pegasusv:/lib/modules/5.19.17$ ls`

`build                      modules.builtin.bin      modules.softdep
kernel                     modules.builtin.modinfo  modules.symbols
modules.alias              modules.dep              modules.symbols.bin
modules.alias.bin          modules.dep.bin          source
modules.builtin            modules.devname
modules.builtin.alias.bin  modules.order
pegasus@pegasusv:/lib/modules/5.19.17$ 
`